# Do good christians go to heaven when they die (Gan Eden)?

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, reward-punishment, olam-haba-world-to-come

Will Christians have a share in the world to come if they truly did not know that Judaism was true, and were brought up with Jesus their whole lives? And can that same concept be applied to atheist as well, who also did not know all the evidence to prove Judaism?

That is to say, does G-d not judge a Christian or atheist for what he or she didn't know?

And if so, for how long?

Comment: Welcome to MY. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Please consider [registering](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Hope to see you around!

Comment: I actually could have sworn I’ve seen this question asked on here before, but I can’t find it at the moment.

Comment: This question will likely be closed for being a duplicate, this doesn't mean it is a bad question, just that there are already answers elsewhere on the site and we don't want to duplicate places for people to answer it

Answer (score 1):

Christians, like all non-Jewish people, are assessed before G-d according to their acceptance of and keeping of the 7 universal commandments of Noah. They are enumerated in chapter 8 of Rambam’s Mishnah Torah, Laws of Kings and Their Wars.

As Rambam explains, these are to a large extent laws which can be reasoned out through normal, human intellect. As the Lubavitcher Rebbe teaches, they are the foundation of civilized society and prevent us from *consuming each other* like wild animals.

These seven commandments are negative (*as in ‘don’t do this*).

According to Torah teaching, reward for fulfillment of negative commandments is spiritual reward *for the soul*, not the body. And it is in this context that Rambam explains righteous non-Jews, meaning those who keep the seven laws of Noah receive a portion in the *World to Come*, like Jews. *Like Jews*, meaning similar to the Jewish portion, not identical. Because the commandments Jews must follow comprise both negative and positive commandments, their portion has both a spiritual and physical component.

It is in this context that the general conception among Christians that their ultimate reward is in Heaven, meaning not physical, is accurate.

Comment: Non Jews have one positive command and six negative commands

Comment: @DoubleAA There are varying opinions among the Rishonim if the commandment regarding establishment of courts of justice is negative or positive. If you take Rambam in the context of what he begins with in Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah, he understands it to be negative.

Comment: If you are basing yourself off strictly Rambam opinion, shouldn't you mention he believes they are ovdei avoda zara?

Comment: @user6591 I'm not. I just pointed to the Mishnah Torah because the requirements for non-Jews are listed clearly. There is no requirement about "knowing Judaism". Although it would seem difficult to imagine someone could have a strong grasp of the subject today without being exposed.